# How to push a custom branch of data to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a database with a branch like that:
[image]

I use a code to push to Firebase:

```
mDatabaseReference.child(Constant.CHILD_CHATONETOONE + "/" + hostUid + "/" + clientUid).push().setValue(new Message("Hi guy"), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if(databaseError!= null)
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

But when I use this code, my app stops working. Seems like Firebase didn't accept my way to take a new branch in database. Here is logcat:

```
10-15 11:46:16.720 3590-3590/com.team2_dtui.heyfriend_v2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.team2_dtui.heyfriend_v2/com.team2_dtui.heyfriend_v2.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at com.team2_dtui.heyfriend_v2.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Inside the logcat: `com.team2_dtui.heyfriend_v2.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43` is the code I gave above.

**When i change this code to one child, it works fine:**

```
mDatabaseReference.child(Constant.CHILD_CHATONETOONE).push().setValue(new Message("Hi guy"), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if(databaseError!= null)
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I can figure out the problem. How can I create this branch in the first time? Help me. I'm a Firebase newbie.

Comment: Is there a logcat for the app stopping?

Comment: i've updated the logcat in my question. the logcat indicated that this code has problem.

Comment: You can use Firebase console and import it as a json file, if it is only for one time.

Comment: @MohsenMirhoseiniArgi so if at the moment I have no data to add then i must to import a sample data? is that right, bro?

Comment: It is possible to create a branch in runtime.

Comment: oh, can u tell me that way? thank u in advance!

Comment: You also have to check you db authentication

Comment: You need to check if `databaseError` field is null or not. Because if the data is saved successfully, it'll return `null`. Please see my answer below. :)

Comment: my app run smoothly :). it just has problem when i put this code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about null variable. And the firebase code works fine. Thank you for though on it.

Answer (score 1):

Only the `setValue` function can do the job for you. Once you go the referenced node and call the function `setValue` to that node, it creates a branch there automatically. So you need to remove the `push` function call.

The other thing is to check if the `databaseError` field is `null`. Here's the Firebase documentation on [adding a completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/save-data#section-completion-callback) for saving data. You need to check if the `databaseError` field is `null` like the example given in the documentation.

So your code might look like this.

```
mDatabaseReference.child(Constant.CHILD_CHATONETOONE + "/" + hostUid + "/" + clientUid).setValue(new Message("Hi guy"), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if(databaseError != null)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: thank u but i want firebase automatically generate uid for each message. so i need to use push() method. how can I make it?

Comment: I see. Then you just need to check the `databaseError` field. Because for successful data saving, it'll return `null` like the example above.

Comment: i wonder if data design has problem. should i put chat field into user field?

Comment: Its still crashing with `NullPointerException`?

Comment: It shouldn't crash. Because, the null value is already checked to avoid the crash.

Comment: I found my problem. It's my variable: hostuid and client. One of them is null so my program has stop working. I forgot check them before call them. Thank u so much!!